# LinkedIn API: token wrongly reported as revoked

Tags: linkedin-api

Our application uses a 3-legged oAuth flow to obtain consent to access the LinkedIn API on behalf of our user. We request the following permissions:

- r_basicprofile
- w_organization_social
- r_organization_admin
- rw_ads
- r_ads_reporting

We  receive an auth code from url: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization and exchange that for a token that should be valid for 2 months via the endpoint: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken

This works momentarily for our user, but after a few minutes further API requests return the following error:

> the token used in the request has been revoked by the user